# Failing to set ProcessDEPPolicy using SetProcessMitigationPolicy

Tags: c++, windows, policy

When trying to set the ProcessDEPPolicy, I am receiving error '50' which is 'unsupported' according to the MS docs but when checking further documentation, I meet all requirements.

```
PROCESS_MITIGATION_DEP_POLICY PMDP{};
PMDP.Enable = 1;
PMDP.Permanent = 1;
if (!SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessDEPPolicy, &PMDP, sizeof(PMDP)))
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    spdlog::critical("Failed to apply ProcessDEPPolicy! Error code: {}", error);
    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
Failed to apply ProcessDEPPolicy! Error code: 50
```

I've tried changing around the values of 'PMDP.Enable' and 'PMDP.Permanent' but of course that didn't work.

Comment: From the docs: *To compile an application that uses this function, set _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0602*. Did you do that?

Comment: @jkb did try that. Same result